# How can I reuse TV cables in my house for networking?

Tags: networking

My house has tv cables terminated in each room. I am not using this anymore and I would like to extend my network to basement without using WiFi. Is it possible to reuse these cables for this purpose? I am a total stranger to DOCSIS, I guess this will be what you might suggest but I have no idea what devices I need and how I have to connect them. Any (others) suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MoCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_over_Coax_Alliance) does exactly what you want. There are also flavors of HomePNA that go over coax, I believe.

Comment: I'm very happy with my MoCA boxes. Don't know about the HomePNA coax version, but I can tell you that the powerline networking was completely incompatible with my radio hobbies.

Comment: powerline killed my wifi as well ....I could not get signal good enough in basement and I wanted to use powerline... big mistake, lots of interference

Answer (score 0):

DOCSIS would require a modem at each termination to bridge between the coaxial cable and an ethernet jack.

Another method is to use the electrical wiring in your house.  You can get adapters that plug into a socket and they have ethernet jacks built into them.  This would avoid wifi while still using the existing infrastructure in your home.

Comment: DOCSIS is very complicated and asymmetrical and would require an expensive CMTS (Cable Modem Termination System; the way-more-complex-than-just-a-modem device that sits at the cable head-end and controls assigning channels and timing to all the modems).